# Adding column wise data in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to add column wise data in C#, for e.g.

I have four columns in datatable i.e. No, productoriginal, productmedium, productmedium and productlarge.

first i want to fill ABC then i want to No then Product then productoriginal then productmedium and productlarge

below is my code

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("No", typeof(Int));
 dt.Columns.Add("productoriginal", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("productmedium", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("productlarge", typeof(string));
```

how do i proceed further ?

Comment: you mean you want to add rows to the table?

Comment: yes, but i have to add rows for column "No" first, then i will write some business logic then i would like to add rows for "productoriginal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to add rows to the `DataTable`, there is a good example on MSDN, but the basics of it is this:

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["No"] = "Value for No here";
row["productoriginal"] = "Value for productoriginal here";
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Take a look into MSDN [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

As mentioned, this is just an example, I'm sure you can amend it as you need to.